# Read cdb file in Java

Tags: java, cdb

I need to read a cdb file in java. I have already tried "strangegizmo" but it is not working as it is giving me an error of invalid cdb format though another tool can read the file.

I have also tried another library "xbird.storage" but in vain.

Here is my sample of codes which i tried :

**strangegizmo:** source : http://www.strangegizmo.com/products/sg-cdb/

```
String cdbFile = "C:\\workspace\\TestProject\\resources\\test.cdb";

    /* Dump the CDB file. */
    try {
        Enumeration e = Cdb.elements(cdbFile);
        while (e.hasMoreElements())  {
            /* Get the element and its component parts. */
            CdbElement element = (CdbElement)e.nextElement();
            byte[] key = element.getKey();
            byte[] data = element.getData();

            /* Write the line directly to stdout to avoid any
             * charset conversion that System.print() might want to
             * perform. */
            System.out.write(
                ("+" + key.length + "," + data.length + ":").getBytes());
            System.out.write(key);
            System.out.write('-');
            System.out.write('>');
            System.out.write(data);
            System.out.write('\n');
        }
        System.out.write('\n');
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't dump CDB file: "
            + ioException);
    }
```

And also **xbird** api source (svn link) : http://xbird.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xbird-open:

```
    /*
     * @(#)$Id$
     *
     * Copyright 2006-2008 Makoto YUI
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     * 
     * Contributors:
     *     Makoto YUI - initial implementation
     */
    package xbird.storage.index;

    import java.io.Closeable;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.ByteOrder;
    import java.nio.CharBuffer;
    import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
    import java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;

    /**
     * 
     * <DIV lang="en"></DIV>
     * <DIV lang="ja"></DIV>
     * 
     * @author Makoto YUI (yuin405+xbird@gmail.com)
     * @link http://d.hatena.ne.jp/odz/20060623/1151107174
     * @link http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/tinycdb.html
     */
    public class ReadOnlyCDB implements Closeable {
        private static final int HASHSTART = 5381;

        /** map for CDB file */
        private ByteBuffer map;

        /** CDB File */
        private RandomAccessFile file;

        /** number of hash slots searched under this key */
        private int loop;

        /** initialized if loop is nonzero */
        private int khash;

        private int kpos;

        private int hpos;

        private int hslots;

        public ReadOnlyCDB(String filename) throws IOException {
            file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
            FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
            map = channel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, file.length());
            map.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);


    //        CharBuffer charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(map);
    //        String text = charBuffer.toString();
    //        System.out.println(text); // AB

            Charset charset = Charset.forName( "us-ascii" );
            CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
            CharBuffer charBuffer = decoder.decode( map );
            String sb = decoder.decode( map ).toString();



    //        map.get(map.hasArray(), map.arrayOffset(), channel.read(map));


            int noOfBytesRead = channel.read(map);

            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {

                while (noOfBytesRead != -1) {

                    map.clear();
                    noOfBytesRead = channel.read(map);
                }
                map.clear();
                channel.position(0);
                noOfBytesRead = channel.read(map);

            }

        }

        public void close() {
            try {
                file.close();
                file = null;
                map = null;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }

        public void findstart() {
            loop = 0;
        }

        public byte[] findnext(byte[] key, int offset, int len) {
            int u;
            int dlen;

            if(loop == 0) {
                u = hash(key, offset, len);
                map.position((u << 3) & 2047);
                hpos = map.getInt();
                hslots = map.getInt();
                if(hslots == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                khash = u;
                u >>>= 8;
                u %= hslots;
                u <<= 3;
                kpos = hpos + u;
            }

            while(loop < hslots) {
                int pos;

                map.position(kpos);
                u = map.getInt();
                pos = map.getInt();
                if(pos == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                loop++;
                kpos += 8;

                if(kpos == hpos + (hslots << 3)) {
                    kpos = hpos;
                }

                if(u == khash) {
                    map.position(pos);
                    u = map.getInt();
                    if(u == len) {
                        dlen = map.getInt();
                        byte[] keyInDb = new byte[len];
                        map.get(keyInDb, 0, len);
                        if(!match(key, offset, len, keyInDb)) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        byte[] data = new byte[dlen];
                        map.get(data, 0, dlen);
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public byte[] findnext(byte[] key) {
            return findnext(key, 0, key.length);
        }


        public byte[] find(byte[] key) {
            return find(key, 0, key.length);
        }

        public byte[] find(byte[] key, int offset, int len) {
            findstart();
            return findnext(key, offset, len);
        }

        private static int hash(byte[] buffer, int offset, int len) {
            long h = HASHSTART;
            final long mask = 0x00000000ffffffffL;
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                h = (h + (h << 5) & mask) & mask;
                h = h ^ ((buffer[offset + i] + 0x100) & 0xff);
            }
            return (int) (h & mask);
        }

        private static boolean match(byte[] key, int offset, int len, byte[] keyInDb) {
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if(key[offset + i] != keyInDb[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
           try {
            ReadOnlyCDB readOnlyCDB = new ReadOnlyCDB("C:\\workspace\\TestProject\\resources\\test.cdb");
    //        System.out.println("Hemant: " + readOnlyCDB.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    }
```

I have been able to read file and put it into CharBuffer in the second sample of code. But i need key and data pairs, Which i have not been able to get out of the the code.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Hemant

Comment: where do you get the cdb file from (what is inside)?

Comment: I got it from one of my telecom node (switch / router).